# How to find the user's documents directory with Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

```
val fr = javax.swing.JFileChooser()
val fw = fr.fileSystemView
val documentsPath = fw.getDefaultDirectory().toString()

println(documentsPath)
```

I tried this code but IDEA said "Use property access syntax"..
Is there a better way?

Answer (score 4):

"Use property access syntax" is an inspection that "reports calls to java get and set methods that can be replaced with use of Kotlin synthetic properties."

i.e. You can replace `fw.getDefaultDirectory()` with `fw.defaultDirectory`.